# Fluenthibernate Mapping Inheritances/Subclass

Tags: c#, nhibernate, inheritance, mapping, fluent

I am new to (Fluent)NHibernate and have a question:

I the following class structure:

```
<!-- language: c# -->
public class JAccount
{
    public virtual long Id { get; private set; }
    //some properties
    public virtual JProfile Profile { get; set; }
}
public class JProfile
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
   //some more properties
    public virtual int Age { get; set; }

}
```

I mapped those classes which worked fine..

```
<!-- language: c# -->
public class JProfileMap : ClassMap<JProfile>
{
    public JProfileMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).Unique().GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        //some more property mappings

    }
}
```

Then i thought, I have a lot of logic (methods) in those entity classes and I wanted to create a new Class for each of them with inherits from the base class and store all logic into it.
So i did something like:

```
<!-- language: c# -->
public class TestAccount : JAccount
{
  //all properties which did not need to be mapped into the DB
  //as well as methods
}
//did the same for JProfile
```

The problem is now, when I load a JAccount from Database and I cast it into TestAccount
and try to save it back, I get an Exception because FluentHibernate does not have a mapping for TestAcccount

My Question is now: Do i really need to SubClassMap this new classes? I dont want/need them to be mapped in the database because all they do is to take out the logik from its base class. IS there maybe a different way of accomplishing this?

Thanks for any help

Comment: It is not possible to have instantiate a `JAccount` and cast it to a `TestAccount`. Can you clarify what you are doing here?

Comment: like i said i wanted to keep the base classes which are mapped as simple as possible. having JUST properties, and another class which inherits from this base class which implements all other things like methods..so i have `TestAccount` class which inherits from `JAccount` with methods like `Register()` but those classes are not mapped because they have no properties/info which need to be stored in the database, they extend just the base class with methods...but i get errors from fluenthibernate when trying to update/save and instance that those classes are not mapped :(

Comment: You can do it the other way around, to tell nhibernate to ignore the base class for example `Profile : Entity` to tell nhibernate to ignore `Entity` but is there a way to do the oposite, ignore profile and save/cast to entity? =D

Answer (score 0):

the type of the object **is** an important info which should be stored in the database. Thats the most important reason why there is a SubclassMapping.

Instead of Inheriting JAccount you could use the strategy pattern to seperate the logic

```
public class JAccount
{
    private AcountType _type;

    public JAccount(AcountType type)
    {
        _type = type;
    }

    public virtual long Id { get; private set; }
    //some properties
    public virtual JProfile Profile { get; set; }

    public void Register()
    {
        _type.Register(this);
    }
}

// in JAccountMap
    References(Reveal.Member<JAccount>("_type")).Access.Field().Not.LazyLoad();
    // or
    Map(Reveal.Member<JAccount>("_type"), "type").CustomType<AccountTypeToStringUserType>();
```

Comment: Yes in most cases that's true but what i tried to is to have a class which represents the table (just properties) and is mapped, and a second class which inhertits those properties and has all logical stuff in it but is not mapped to the database.. however I guess my attempt what i wanna do is wrong/logical wrong ...

Comment: if there are more than one inheriting class, how do you know which one to apply on the mapped class? if it is a column in the database you could just map the hierarchy and be done